# hibernate+jpa+postgresql: no dialet mapping

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

i used a native query to call a function in my postgresql database, code is like this:

```
String query = "select details,rec_xml[1] from f_get_reccomendations(\'/ma:recommendations/ma:recommendation/name/text()\') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query); 
return q.getResultList();
```

the function defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_reccomendations (
  IN  xpath    varchar(128),
  OUT id       int,
  OUT recs_num int,
  OUT details  varchar(25),
  OUT d_stamp  timestamp,
  OUT rec_xml  xml[]
) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
select id, recs_num, details, d_stamp, xpath($1, recs,
          array [
                  array['xs','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'],
                  array['ma','http://schemas.medio.com/analytics/1.0']
                ]
          ) from recommendations;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

when ran from the psql, it worked, but when i run in the code, it threw me error:
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2009

my guess is the rec_xml is defined  as xml[] type that hibernate could not understand? how can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Are you sure it's the array of XML, not the xml type its self, that's the issue? I've found Hibernate's support for Pg's XML type to be somewhere between poor and nonexistent.

If it proves to be the array: Try expanding the array of xml into a set, so you return the cross join of `recs' and the rest of the results. This will require filtering on the client side to de-duplicate results.

Alternately, you could write a dialect type mapping for xml[] in Hibernate, or cast the xml to text so you return text[].